# Conditionally iterating through each value in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've put together a small database to keep track of some accumulator bets that a few of my colleagues and I place during the football season. Now I need to write a function to calculate the winnings for each selection. The key table is selection with the key fields for the function being odds and result_id where a result_id of 1 is a win. The stake is stored in the bet table. Below is the selection table which has two winners for bet_id 1, so the resulting equation would be ((@stake * 1.40) * 1.40). Is there a way using a cursor or a set based method to generate this value?

```
bet_id  punter_id   team_id odds    result_id   ground_id
1       1           24      1.40    1           1
1       1           48      1.60    2           1
1       1           89      1.60    2           1
1       2           8       1.40    1           1
1       2           11      1.60    2           1
1       2           107     1.60    2           1
```

Comment: Shouldn't need a cursor to do this. What joins the bet table to the selection table? Bet_id?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Yeah I don't understand your question at all.

Comment: Just add a new column something like this: ((@stake * odds) * odds) as winnings

Comment: @Leonidas199x yes the relationship is bet_id

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you join on `bet_id`:

```
CREATE TABLE bet (bet_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
                  stake float NOT NULL); -- or some floating point number type
```

To multiply a group we use the following relationship:

```
log( a * b * c ) = log(a) + log(b) + log(c)
```

And therefore for multiplication

```
a * b * c = exp( log( a * b * c ) ) = exp( sum( log(.) ) )
```

To calculate the factors

```
bet_id | odds_factor 
1      | 1.40 * 1.40 = 1.96
```

we use the Common Table Expression CTE in this query

```
WITH factor( bet_id, odds_factor ) AS 
  ( SELECT bet_id, exp( sum( log( odds ) ) ) 
    FROM selection 
    WHERE result_id = 1  -- only winning odds in the grouping
    GROUP BY bet_id ) 
SELECT b.bet_id, 
       b.stake, 
       f.odds_factor, 
       b.stake * f.odds_factor AS "total_odds" 
FROM bet b
INNER JOIN factor f 
ON b.bet_id = f.bet_id 
-- ORDER BY b.bet_id -- optional ordering for readability
```

which should yield (untested)

```
bet_id | stake | odds_factor | total_odds 
1      | 10.0  | 1.96        | 19.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Think this is as simple as:

```
SELECT      B.BET_ID, 
            S.PUNTER_ID,
            ((B.stake * S.odds) * S.odds)
FROM        BET         AS B
INNER JOIN  SELECTION   AS S ON B.Bet_id = S.Bet_id
WHERE       S.result_id = 1
```